# JavaScript Prototype Functions

Tags: javascript, prototype

What is the difference between these functions? And what are the advantages and disadvantages?

```
let Test = function(name) {
  this.name = name;
  this.complete = function() {
    console.log(`completing task${this.name}`)
  }
}
```

and

```
let Test = function(name) {
  this.name = name;
}

Test.prototype.complete = function() {
  console.log(`completing task${this.name}`)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that each object you will create with the first function would have it's separate instance of `complete` function. While each object you will create with the second function would share the same `complete` function, which can be found at the prototype of the object you create using `Test`.

So if you create 100 objects using the first function, all these objects would have a different reference in memory for the `complete` function. While in the second case you would have only one, since all these objects would find the `complete` function on their prototype.